# Using Nose & NoseXUnit on a Python package

Tags: python, package, web2py, nose, nosetests

[This is a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225598/pretty-continuous-integration-for-python) detailing a CI setup for Python. The asker and answerer detail the use of *Nose* and *NoseXUnit* with Hudson for their builds.  However, *NoseXUnit* throws an error when run on any source folder where **init**.py is present:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/nosexunit/tools.py", line 59, 
    in packages nosexunit.excepts.ToolError: following folder can not contain 
    __init__.py file: /home/dev/source/web2py/applications
```

I can't think of a source folder of mine that is not a package also.  Is there a step I am missing when dealing with *NoseXUnit*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use NoseXUnit - it's really out of date, and a similar feature exists in nose >= 0.11.

From nose --help:

```
  --with-xunit          Enable plugin Xunit: This plugin provides test results
                        in the standard XUnit XML format. [NOSE_WITH_XUNIT]
  --xunit-file=FILE     Path to xml file to store the xunit report in. Default
                        is nosetests.xml in the working directory
                        [NOSE_XUNIT_FILE]
```

if for some reason you need an old version of nose, use http://bitbucket.org/durin42/nose-xml/ - that's the plugin that became the --with-xunit option.